# React Native: is there any difference between implementing conditional rendering with ternary vs &&?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, conditional-rendering

In my React Native app, I want to render a `<View>` conditional on variable `var`. There are two ways I've tried doing this:

1)

```
{var && <View/>}
```

2. 

```
{var ? <View/> : null}
```

Is there an advantage of one over the other?

Comment: Your second option gives better compatibility with React 17, if `var` could be `undefined`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference is in method 2, the falsey expression can be rendered. Take this example, which will render `<div>0</div>` instead of an empty div as you might expect.

```
render() {
  const count = 0;
  return (
    <div>
      {count && <View />}
    </div>
  );
}
```

[Conditional rendering docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html).

Comment: Also in React 17, `undefined` would cause issues.  But in React 18, `undefined` acts like `null` now and will render empty.